# 3D Polyline (or any path) in Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, 3d, maps, polyline

Good day,

Short question:
Is it possible to draw a 3D polyline, or any other path shape for that matter, in the version 2 API of Google Maps? I see no parameters for altitude.

The maps are now supposed to be 3D, altough, apart from some clever shading, when I tilt the map, it still looks rather flat. This made me wonder if it was really truly 3D, and if it was not better to wait until API v3 is fully functional.

Thanks in advance
Wessel

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, it does not answer my question really :) I have already gone through all the Google documentation I could find, and came to the conclusion that it is not possible. However, before giving up, I thought I would post here to check if I am not maybe missing something obvious.

Comment: Does no one know the answer to this question?