# 3d map view using android map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, 3d

I have already checked out couple of links and posts made here about 3d map view using android map v2 like:

[3D Polyline (or any path) in Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313582/3d-polyline-or-any-path-in-google-maps-api-v2)

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/12/new-google-maps-android-api-now-part-of.html

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.ar/2012/12/better-maps-in-your-android-apps.html

http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/

[3D maps library for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997098/3d-maps-library-for-android)

I have also checked out  Trulia, Expedia Hotels and FlightTrack links they are doing it great but somehow I couldn't find the way to show that

I have even checked out Panorama view through this link:
https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/wiki/UserGuide

but still i am unable to implement 3d map view using android map v2

may be im missing out something

can anyone give me a simple to the point tutorial or example which will show properly how to show map in 3d view in v2 only not v3 or in webview

thanks

Answer (score 8):

at last i found the answer for it , the map v2 have default 3d maps in it and its only enabled in newyork,cannada etc..use this code

it works perfectly and try tilt view and it can be made by keeping two fingers in the map and dragging two fingers downwards and the magic will happen 
hope it u find it useful

```
          CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
             .target() // Sets the center of the map to
               .zoom()                   // Sets the zoom
             .bearing() // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
             .tilt()    // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
             .build();    // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
         mapp.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
             cameraPosition));
```

Comment: CameraPosition only allows to tilt and all those extra stuffs to change the camera angle, but it doesn't provide a 3D view to the map, I hope you have checked out the links I have provided, that is not possible using cameraposition, and neither am i sitting in newyork,cannada    so can you give me any other ways??